# Replacing space between json.loads elements with comma

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I have the following code:

```
for myvar in json.loads(myjson):

                print myvar['var1'], myvar['var2'], myvar['var3']
```

This is printing results in the manner of:

```
var1 var2 var3
```

But I would like it it print it in the manner of:

```
var1,var2,var3
```

How can I replace the space between the elements of the json load with a comma?

Thanks

Comment: That is completely unrelated to JSON, and would happen with any list of lists. As a minimal fix, just `str.format` the items into a string with commas yourself and `print` that.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the values in a list, and then use the `join` method of `str`.

```
vars = [myvar['var1'], myvar['var2'], myvar['var3']]
print ",".join(vars)
```